# Formatting date time with entity framework query not sorting correctly with ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Tags: entity-framework, sorting, datetime

I'm running a EF query and one column is a nullable StartDate. I need to format the date like this 'MM/dd/yyyy' but I'm running into problems with the way EF is sorting.

At first I tried ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") by ASC but the results don't sort by year first, then month and lastly day. They sort by month then day then year.

ex.

01/01/2010

02/01/2010

03/01/2010

01/01/2011

```
StartDateString = (r.StartDate != null) ? ((DateTime)r.StartDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

So then I tried .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") and that works to sort by year, then month and lastly day but I need it to be in a different format, it needs to be "MM/dd/yyyy"

Am I performing this correctly, is there another way to write this query to get the format I want while sorting correctly?

Any help will be much appreciated.

The order by part looks like this

```
recordsVM = recordsVM.OrderBy(c => c.StartDate)
```

I just tried

```
 recordsVM = recordsVM.OrderBy(c => c.StartDate.Value.Year).ThenBy(c => c.StartDate.Value.Month).ThenBy(c => c.StartDate.Value.Day);
```

but now it's throwing an error an not returning anything

Comment: You've only shown little bits of what's going on. I'd expect you to be able to order by the StartDate *then* project that to whatever format you want. (Personally I'd do the formatting within .NET rather than as part of the SQL, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: can you provide some example of what you mean when you say "project" to a format?

Comment: Using `Select`, which is I assume what you're doing with `StartDateString = ...`. (It's hard to tell as we can only see snippets of your code.) A `Select` call *projects* the results of the query so far into a potentially-different shape.

Comment: Sort using the actual data type and format at the UI level.

Comment: sorting at the UI level is what I need to avoid!

Comment: No, sort _then_ format (at the UI level).

Comment: I can't format at the UI level. This page fetches 500 rows from a table and displays them, if each date (start, end) in each row are formatted in the Vue app it would take too long to render. So it needs to be done server side